# struggling to use datetimepicker on Bootstrap 4 on NPM

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am struggling to make datetimepicker work on Bootstrap4 with `npm`, I don't have any error when I compile the code and I don't have any error in the inspector, and the plugin is working but it seems like it doesn't load the CSS for some reason.

Here is what I have tried already:

```
 npm i bootstrap4-datetimepicker
```

Then I have imported datetimepicker in my JS files with

```
import 'bootstrap4-datetimepicker';
```

and I have imported the datetimepicker CSS in my mean SCSS file with:

```
@import "~bootstrap4-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap4-datetimepicker.css"
```

I don't have any JS error at all so all the files are imported properly.

Here is my HTML file:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker-disabled-days">
```

Here is my JS file:

```
 import 'bootstrap4-datetimepicker';
 ...
 $('#datepicker-disabled-days').datetimepicker(
     format: 'LT'
 );
 ...
```

The calendar appears when I click on the input field but it doesn't have CSS. Here is the result that I want to achieve http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I am open to using another module if the module can be used to select dates and times.

Comment: Do you have a codesandbox for your error?

Comment: Yes I do have a sandbox but it doesn't have any errors regarding this. I think that this module is not suitable for bootstrap 4 and it is using CSS classes that bootstrap 4 doesn't got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem in this way: This module gives the possibility to display custom icons in the calendar, I use fontawsome icons css classes to display the arrow up and arrow down,

Here is the code:

```
      $('#datetimepicker8').datetimepicker({
          icons: {
              up: "fa angle-up",
              down: "fa angle-down"
          }
      });
```

In order to select the hh:mm format:

```
 $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
     format: 'LT'
 });
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might be using a bad path (`~<some_path>` vs `~/<some_path>`). Try `@import "~/bootstrap4-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap4-datetimepicker.css"`

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately, the `/` didn't help, the CSS file is imported correctly, I think that this module is not suitable for Bootstrap4 and my version of bootstrap doesn't have the CSS markups of the datetimepicker calendar.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be curious to know where this is happening:

```js
@import "~bootstrap4-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap4-datetimepicker.css"
```

I feel like last time I did something like this I still needed to include the css in the index.html. I'd give that a shot if you encounter this again or don't want to include unnecessary libraries.

Also that path to the css file doesn't look quite right.